# How do I write a unit test to call a function inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write a unit test using jest and react testing library. I want to test a function call inside the useEffect hook, but my test is not working. What do I need to do to pass the test successfully?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getActiveFilters(filterValue);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [filterValue, dictionaries]);
```

Here my test

```
  it('should call the [getActiveFilters] function', async () => {
    const getActiveFilters = jest.fn();
    await waitFor(() => expect(getActiveFilters).toHaveBeenCalled());
  });
```

[image]

Comment: You're just creating a new variable and setting it to be a `jest.fn()`... there's no connection to the component you want to test. Test the results of this function (eg. some changes in the rendered content), not the implementation of some function..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that it is hard to mock function in component. You should using spy(test double) for some module. The way that check rendering elements in document properly is also good idea.

Here is my example.

##### Test Code

```js
    it('axios spy and rendering test', async () => {

        const spyAxios = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValue({
            data: 'Junhyunny'
        });

        render(<SecondAuth />);

        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(screen.getByText('Sir Junhyunny')).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
        expect(spyAxios).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 'http://localhost:8080', {
            params: {}
        });
    });
```

##### Component

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const SecondAuth = () => {

    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080', {
            params: {}
        }).then(({data}) => {
            setName(data);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Sir {name}</p>
        </div>
    );

};

export default SecondAuth;
```